# ImageView Or CardView opening another activity onClick

Tags: android, onclick, imageview, onclicklistener

This is one of the CardViews in my gridView and I want to link it to my other activity but every time I get errors (onClickListener turns red and doesn't work) or app crashes...

(I already have linked my floating button to another activity)

*These CardViews that im gonna be using as buttons*
https://i.gyazo.com/581787f5fcba5355c9265a7b75a8f663.png

XML:

```
      <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/rowOneColOne"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/gridBg"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/everythingaboutme"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

JAVA:

```
 public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

 private static ImageView imgview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);



    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            {
                Intent website = new Intent(Home.this , website.class);
                startActivity(website);

            }


        }
    });
}

public void OnclickButtonListener() {

    imgview =  findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    imgview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Portfolio = new Intent(Home.this,Portfolio.class);
            startActivity(Portfolio);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to edit your post with the errors/stacktrace

Comment: @codeMagic i just need to know how i can link that card view to another activity without crashing the app :/

Comment: And we just need to know why it's crashing to help you figure out what you did wrong and to help you understand why it is

Comment: @codeMagic now that I use this code I don't get any error... the app crashes or the onClickListener doesn't work...

Comment: @codeMagic I tried both, linking the ImageView and CardView but it doesnt work

Comment: If the app crashes, there are logs in your stacktrace. So, again, edit your post with the stacktrace from the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddy do you realise that you have placed binding of imageview and its corresponding onclicklistener setting inside the function OnClickButton listener **which is outside the onCreate method**. 
You have call the function **OnClickButtonListener();** inside of **onCreate** method of your class to actually register the binding and setting clicklistener on that imageview.

Comment: could you explain more please... I didn't really understand what you mean caz I'm just a beginner

Comment: sure buddy. All the functions that you want to use are primarily called from the onCreate method of your java class. So, after creating your OnClickButtonListener() function, you have to call this function in the onCreate method also. Just write the line "OnClickButtonListener();" within the onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method of your java class and the function would be called as intended.